# Pseudo elements on Polymer custom element does not work

Tags: polymer

Pseudo elements on custom elements created via Polymer do not seem to work when added from inside the template. I tried the following variations, but none of them work.

```
:host(:before), :host(::before) {
    content: 'before';
}

:host:before, :host:before {
    content: 'before';
}
```

I know that pseudo elements does work when applied from outside the custom element. For example,

```
custom-element::after {
    content: 'after';
}
```

Maybe I am not using the right syntax but the Polymer project page doesn't mention about using them either. I like to keep all the css styles applied to the custom element in one place.

But the inability to style pseudo elements from within the custom element is a big constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was recently fixed in http://crbug.com/393509. It should be in Chrome 38.

Comment: Is this a chrome only problem? And once shipped what will be the correct syntax?

Comment: Right now yes. Chrome is the only browser shipping native Shadow DOM. `:host()::before` and `:host::after` will be the syntax.

Comment: I just realised that `::before` and `::after` doesn't work in Chrome and Opera only (Blink browers). They seem to be working perfectly on Firefox and Safari when using Polymer (non-Blink browsers).